# Deleting a row in AdvancedDataGrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a AdvancedDataGrid i want to delete the row on button click.
my code is

```
[Bindable]
        private var sales:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Sno:"1",categoryName:"biscuits", 
                description:"salt"}, 
            {Sno:"2",categoryName:"biscuits", 
                description:"cream"}, 
            {Sno:"3",categoryName:"sweets", 
                description:"less sweet"}, 
            {Sno:"4",categoryName:"sweets", 
                description:"normal sweet"}, 
            {Sno:"5",categoryName:"fruits", 
                description:"healthy "}, 
            {Sno:"6",categoryName:"fruits", 
                description:"sweetfruits"}]);
private function deleteRows():void{

            sales.removeItemAt(myADG1.selectedIndex);
        }
```

and my grid is

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG1" width="100%" height="100%" contentBackgroundColor="#F7F0F0"
                     initialize="gc.refresh();" variableRowHeight="true"  >        
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:GroupingCollection2 id="gc" source="{sales}">
            <mx:grouping>
            <mx:Grouping label="Sno">
                <mx:GroupingField name="categoryName"/>
            </mx:Grouping>
            </mx:grouping>
        </mx:GroupingCollection2>
    </mx:dataProvider>        

    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="125" dataField="Sno" headerText="Sno"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="175" dataField="categoryName" headerText="CategoryName"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="150" dataField="description" headerText="categoryDescription"/>

    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

sales is my datatprovider . the above code is not deleting selected rows.can any one help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a grouping collection, you have to take the `selectedItem` from the grid, and look up it's index in the original `ArrayCollection`:

```
private function deleteRows():void {
    var index:int = sales.getItemIndex(myADG1.selectedItem);
    if (index != -1) {
        sales.removeItemAt(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: even if i not use MYADG1.invalidateList(); the rows are deleting but it is not deleting selected row, it is deleting some other row.thanks for your response. can you suggest me some other means to do that.

Comment: Are you using a filter or sort applied to data provider? Inspect the object that is being returned by `getItemAt(myADG1.selectedIndex)`, in the debugger or by using trace statements, is it what you expect? Show more code and the results of any thing you did to figure it out.

Comment: Hai sunil thanks for your response. I have added my grid and dataprovider can you check where i am going wrong. what my boss said as we are grouping the index value of grid and dataprovider will not be equal so only the selected row is not deleting. can you please check it

Comment: @user2083041 the `GroupingCollection2` explains the difference. I'm editing my answer...

Comment: hello sunil. for resetting datagrid dp =new ArrayCollection() works fine but it is not working with advanced datagrid where dp is my dataprovider. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using the `GroupingCollection2`, you would need to reset the `ArrayCollection` that is wrapped by `GroupingCollection2`: `gc.source = new ArrayCollection()`